# Django 3.1 gives error | URLconf does not have any pattern in it, If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably

Tags: python, django, url

**Python: 3.6.0 | Django: 3.1.4**

By going through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/), I created one app, below is my app url.py (from app) file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

My site urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('npimgapp/', include('npimgapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

My view.py file in app

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome ...")
```

On executing this code I am getting below error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
> 'npimgpro.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see
> valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a
> circular i mport.

Also, below is my directory structure for ref:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directory structure is wonky; there shouldn't be two nested `npimgpro` folders.

Move the contents of that `npimgpro` folder up one level, so it's

- npimgpro/

  - (etc.)
- npimgapp/

  - (etc.)
- manage.py
- db.sqlite3

[image]